# Ecommerce bundle for Synfony 2

Tags: symfony

I want to add ecommerce function to an existing LMS project on top of symfony2. I checked elcodi and sylius. Both seem very complicate and lack good documentation on how to integrate into an existing project. I need only order, payment, maybe cart. Anyone can recommend an ecommerce bundle that fit my need? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This, Symfony e-commerce bundle and shop components

https://github.com/aimeos/aimeos-symfony